# MVC EF - Inner Join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I checked the questions that may already have my answer but it seems that none of them addresses the issue I have:

```
var semesters = db.Semesters.Where(e => e.ID == semester).ToList();
var semestersbyfaculty = db.SemestersByFaculty.Where(e => e.FacultyID == id).ToList();
```

How do I inner join these two queries like if I do the following in SQL:

```
SELECT 
   Fac.*, Sem.SemesterText
FROM 
   SemestersByFaculty AS Fac
INNER JOIN
   Semesters AS Sem
ON
   Fac.SemesterID = Sem.ID
WHERE id
   Fac.FacultyID = id
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [Inner Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_0)

The following example shows a simple inner equijoin.

```
var query = from fac in db.SemesterByFaculty
            join sem in db.Semester on fac.SemesterID equals sem.ID
            where fac.FacultyID == id
            select new { Faculty = fac, SemesterText = sem.SemesterText };
```

For more information, see [How to: Perform Inner Joins (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx).

UPDATE:

from comments

Models

```
class MyModel {
    public MitModel.SemestersByFacul‌​ty Faculty{ get; set; }
    public string SemesterText { get; set; }
}

class MyViewModel {
    public List<MyModel> SemesterFaculties { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string id) {

    var query = from fac in db.SemesterByFaculty
                join sem in db.Semester on fac.SemesterID equals sem.ID
                where fac.FacultyID == id
                select new MyModel{ Faculty = fac, SemesterTest = sem.SemesterTest };

    var viewModel = new MyViewModel { SemesterFaculties = query.ToList() };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

View

```
@Model MyViewModel
```

Comment: Do you maybe know how do i use this query in the view printing the returned semesters? I assign it to ViewBag and then in the View i have the following: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`2[MitModel.SemestersByFaculty,System.String]]

Comment: In that case you should create a class/model to store the object and use that. Why are you using the ViewBag and not passing it in the model to the View?

Comment: Meaning i have the models SemestersByFaculy and Semesters but not sure how to write the new model? Should i mix/combine the existing model or to have a totally new model contains only values that i need to be displayed?

Comment: It's a good practice to create a viewmodel for that action that contains only what is necessary for the view.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have following fields in `SemestersByFaculty`

```
class SemestersByFaculty
{
    string FacultyName;
    int FacultyID;
    int SemesterID;
}
```

Note : If you have more fields in `SemestersByFaculty` class then you can list them in `new{}` in query below:

```
var query = semesters.Join(semestersbyfaculty,
                                sem => sem.ID,
                                fac => fac.SemesterID,
                                (sem, fac) =>
                                    new { facName = fac.FacultyName, facId = fac.FacultyID,semText = sem.SemesterText }).Where(e=> e.fac.FacultyId = id);
```

Now , what you have got yourself is an enumerable. You can iterate over it and retrieve the values. It will be like:

```
foreach (var obj in query){

   Console.writeln("{0}-{1}-{2}",obj.facName,obj.facId,obj.semText);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution with non-LINQ syntax. Also you can perform 'Where' filter on 'db.Semesters' and 'db.SemestersByFaculty' before they are passed into 'join'.

```
var result = db.SemestersByFaculty
  .Where(
    x_ => x_.FacultyID == id)
  .Join(
    db.Semesters.Where(x_ => x_.ID == semester), 
    x_ => x_.SemesterID, 
    x_ => x_.ID, 
    (x_, y_) => new 
    { 
      FacultyID = x_.ID, 
      SemesterID = y_.SemesterID,
      Sem = y_.SemesterText 
    })
  .ToList();
```